# Why TextMate "-w" option doesn't work?

Tags: macos, bash, textmate

I use MacBook Air with OSX 10.7.2 and TextMate Version 1.5.10 (1631).

If I type:

```
mate -w 1.txt
```

and then close TextMate, the shell doesn't return (i.e. I don't get the shell prompt back).

According to `mate --help`:

```
-w, --wait             Wait for file to be closed by TextMate.
```

Any ideas why `-w` option doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It works for me on 10.7.2 / 1.5.10. Have you tried running it with default TextMate or terminal configurations?

Comment: Just tried it 10.7.2/1.5.10: `mate -w a.txt` and indeed, it does not work - the prompt does not return when TextMate is closed. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: This is actually the same question as ["Alias that allows to edit ~/.bashrc and then “sources” it automatically - Why it doesn't work?"](http://superuser.com/questions/360461/).  The only reason that things failed in that other question in the first place is that this behaviour occurs; and an answer to this question is an answer to that question as well.

Comment: @Lri: I run it with a default TextMate.

Comment: Do you have this problem (and the bashrc problem JdeBP linked to) with a different user account on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because in 10.8 the document isn't truly closed if you do a cmd-Q and quit.  I found that my normal behavior was to just quit after editing, but this leaves the document "open" and the command line doesn't return.  If, however, you do a cmd-w (or close the window), it seems to work properly.

I "think" this is a result of Mtn. Lion's new "keep documents open between launches" feature.

Comment: Only that Mountain Lion wasn't even released when this question was posted :)